# Books about amputee that searches for lost fae

Tags: story-identification, books

Double amputee is recruited out of a drug rehab by a secret organization that is investigating a missing fae? Takes place in Hollywood? In the end we learn that the culprit is

> the movie director.

What is this book?

Comment: Do you happen to recall whether the double amputee is male or female, and whether he/she is missing both arms, or both legs, or one arm and one leg? What is a fae? You say a movie director is "the culprit" but you haven't mentioned any crime, what was it? By the way, is anything about this book fantasy or science fiction?

Comment: Female, missing both legs (happened in a fire? related to her drug use). Fae is the race of “fairy” that live both in this world and their own dimension. The male fae that was kidnapped was the muse of the director but their link was eroding so the director kidnapped him so he could make another movie. I remember thawed were demons that also lived like humans in the book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is *[The Arcadia Project](https://www.goodreads.com/series/155622-the-arcadia-project)* by Mishell Baker. The first book in the series ([*Borderline*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25692886-borderline)) matches your description nicely.

> A year ago Millie lost her legs and her filmmaking career in a failed suicide attempt. Just when she's sure the credits have rolled on her life story, she gets a second chance with the Arcadia Project: a secret organization that polices the traffic to and from a parallel reality filled with creatures straight out of myth and fairy tales.
>
> For her first assignment, Millie is tasked with tracking down a missing movie star, who also happens to be a nobleman of the Seelie Court. To find him, she'll have to smooth talk Hollywood power players and uncover the surreal and sometimes terrifying truth behind the glamour of Tinseltown. But stronger forces than just her inner demons are sabotaging her progress, and if she fails to unravel the conspiracy behind the noble's disappearance, not only will she be out on the streets, but the shattering of a centuries-old peace could spark an all-out war between worlds.

Comment: YES! You have seriously made my day! Thank you :)

Comment: [Always a pleasure.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)